PJSUA2 Python Video Call Supportt
I am trying to make a video call in python and it fails with error Assertion failed: call->opt.vid_cnt == 0, file ../src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_call.c, line 682.
I tested the pjsua-x86_64-w64-mingw32.exe and video calls works fine but after creating the python extension using swig, I still cannot use video calls.
I did add video support options as per the documentation
and here is the sample code to test the video call
import pjsua2 as pj


ep = pj.Endpoint()
ep.libCreate()

ep_cfg = pj.EpConfig()
ep_cfg.logConfig.level = 2
ep.libInit(ep_cfg)

transport_cfg = pj.TransportConfig()
transport_cfg.port = 5060
ep.transportCreate(pj.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, transport_cfg)


ep.libStart()


acc_cfg = pj.AccountConfig()
acc_cfg.idUri = "sip:<number>@<sip provider>"
acc_cfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:<sip provider>"
acc_cfg.sipConfig.authCreds.append(pj.AuthCredInfo("digest", "*", "<number>", 0, "<passwd>"))
acc_cfg.videoConfig.autoTransmitOutgoing = True
acc_cfg.videoConfig.autoShowIncoming = True

acc = pj.Account()
acc.create(acc_cfg)


dst_uri = "sip:<number>@<sip provider>"
call = pj.Call(acc)
param = pj.CallOpParam()
param.opt.audioCount = 1
param.opt.videoCount = 1
call.makeCall(dst_uri, param) # error happens here


call.hangup(param)
ep.libDestroy()

I expect there is an issue with swig as the pjsua-x86_64-w64-mingw32.exe file works fine with video.
Thanks
